# Selecting string value and convert / cast to a date

Tags: sql, wordpress, date, mariasql

I am trying to join two tables from MariaDB and convert a longtext (which I assume is the same as a string?) to a date.

I've searched through a few forums and read some of the MariaDB documentation, but I'm not a proficient SQL coder, so I've probably got the syntax wrong somewhere, and would appreciate any help you can give.

The data in the 'membership_expiry_date' is not compulsory - some entries are NULL, but where there is a date its a longtext in the following format: 
2019/12/31 (YYYY/mm/dd)

```
SELECT u1.`ID` AS 'User ID',
       u1.`user_login` AS 'Website ID',
       m1.meta_value AS 'Last Name',
       m2.meta_value AS 'First Name',
       m3.meta_value AS 'Subs Expire',

FROM dbName_users u1
       LEFT JOIN dbName_usermeta m1 ON (m1.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND m1.`meta_key` = 'last_name')
       LEFT JOIN dbName_usermeta m2 ON (m2.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND m2.`meta_key` = 'first_name')
       LEFT JOIN dbName_usermeta m3 ON (m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND m3.`meta_key` = STR_TO_DATE('membership_expiry_date', '%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Basically I need to pull the date out as a date so I can manipulate it later, which I can't do if it's a string.

If I've managed to get this (or some other variant) code to run, the results so far have been NULL.

**UPDATE**
So I'm using the code below in the wpDataTable WordPress Plugin and whilst I think it's taking the 'membership_expiry_date' and producing a DATE column ('Subs_Expire'), I'm unable to manipulate the column in wpDataTables plugin like a DATE column. 
I know this because I added the 'User_Registered' column that contains DATETIME data and does have the greater than and less than operators available in the conditional formatting options, but the 'Subs_Expire' column doesn't.

I have tried using CAST() and CONVERT() with a variety of DATE / TIME options instead of STR_TO_DATE(), but no luck.

I have posted a query on the TMS website, coders of wpDataTables, to see if they can help: https://tmsplugins.ticksy.com/ticket/1989889/

```
SELECT u1.`ID` AS `User ID`,
       u1.`user_login` AS `Website_ID`,
       u1.`user_registered` AS `User_Registered`,
       m1.meta_value AS `Last_Name`,
       m2.meta_value AS `First_Name`,
       STR_TO_DATE(m3.meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d') as `Subs_Expire`,

FROM dbName_users u1 LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m1
     ON m1.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
        m1.`meta_key` = 'last_name' LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m2
     ON m2.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
        m2.`meta_key` = 'first_name' LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m3
     ON m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
         m3.`meta_key` = 'membership_expiry_date';
```

Answer (score 0):

your last sentence could be like this.

> LEFT JOIN icxdx_usermeta m3 ON (m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
>   m3.`meta_key` = (SELECT CAST(membership_expiry_date AS DATE))

I guess this statement has to work. But it could create error for null. give it a try.

Comment: I tried this based on what you said:

`LEFT JOIN dbName_usermeta m3 ON (m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND m3.`meta_key` = (SELECT CAST(membership_expiry_date AS DATE)))`

but it threw up the error:
MySQL said: Unknown column 'membership_expiry_date' in 'field list'

So I tried this:

`LEFT JOIN dbName_usermeta m3 ON (m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND m3.`meta_key` = (SELECT CAST('membership_expiry_date' AS DATE)))`
and it just pulled lots of other information from the DB into the 'Subs Expire' column and still didn't parse the string as a date...

Thanks though.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

You need the matching condition on the key in the `ON` clause and the conversion in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT u1.`ID` AS `User ID`,
       u1.`user_login` AS `Website ID`,
       m1.meta_value AS `Last Name`,
       m2.meta_value AS `First Name`,
       STR_TO_DATE(m3.meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d')) as `Subs Expire`
FROM dbName_users u1 LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m1
     ON m1.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
        m1.`meta_key` = 'last_name' LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m2
     ON m2.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
        m2.`meta_key` = 'first_name' LEFT JOIN
     dbName_usermeta m3
     ON m3.`user_id` = u1.`ID` AND
        m3.`meta_key` = 'membership_expiry_date';
```

I think it is bad practice to have column aliases with spaces.  If you must, then use backticks (or double quotes) for the delimiter.  Only use single quotes for string and date constant values.

Comment: Thank for your help Gordon, I've taken on board what you said.
I tweaked the line to use: `STR_TO_DATE(m3.meta_value, '%Y/%m/%d') as `Subs_Expire`` and while it accepts the code (no errors) the table it's producing seems to be dates in column, but I still can't manipulate them as such - so there must be something else going on.